# How to disable dummy companion app (only wear part should be extracted to wear)

Tags: android, wear-os

I have developed an android wear application and generated a signed mobile apk with a wear apk embedded in it. Currently it's under alpha testing.

Once after installing the app, the phone app is getting installed on the phone and the wear app is getting pushed to the wear device.

Phone app is a dummy app with only hello world text, I have created this dummy phone app with the purpose to push the wear app to android wear.

Now the question is after installing the app, how can I extract only the wear apk to android wear without installing the dummy phone app on phone?

Because it might not be a good experience for an user to see a helloworld text in the phone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three-part answer:

First, with the arrival of Wear 2.0, "companion" apps will no longer be needed for distribution. Full details here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Second, while you're still supporting Wear 1.x, you could do something useful with your companion app's launcher `Activity` - even if it's only displaying some text like *To use this app's functionality, run it on your watch*. Because there will always be some less-knowledgeable users who expect to run an app from the launcher, and need some hand-holding.

Third: why do you even have an `Activity` with the launcher intent at all? Why not simply remove it from your package, or at least your manifest?